# Jquery to get width of child table

Tags: jquery, html

This might be a very simple question but i am unable to get it. How to get the width of the table which is the child of the div with class "test" using jquery

```
<div class="test">
<div id="one">
</div>
<table>
<thead>
    <th>Test1</th>
    <th>Test2</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                12
            </td>
            <td>
                34
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In the above code, table is not a child of div.test. It is outside the div.

Comment: the </div> of div.test is not coming up in the code above. don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
$(".test > table").width();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("div.test table").width()
```